# How to get value from datagridview combobox?

Tags: c#, datagrid

How to get value from datagridview combobox after selected value is changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
var value = DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value
```

NOTE: You would supply the correct row and cell number.

Or you can do something like this if it is bound to an object like ListItem

```
string value = DataGridView.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

if DataGridView.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxCell && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
     List<ListItem> items = ((DataGridViewComboBoxCellDataGridView.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToList();
     ListItem item = items.Find(i => i.Value.Equals(value));
}
```

Comment: I try to read it in CellContentClick event but without success. How can read it after selected value is changed.

Comment: Try consuming the CellValueChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass to give column name

```
 string SelectedText = Convert.ToString((Pass_dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["Partner"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).FormattedValue.ToString());
```