# How do I check if a combobox in a datagridview equals a certain value?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm creating an ordering system for booking customers in, and I want a combobox in a datagridview to be able to mark a certain job as complete, and change the colour of that row to green when yes is selected, I'd like some help with this please as I have no idea how to do it, I have looked all over the internet and found nothing.

this is a screenshot of the database, any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using WinForms

thanks in advance[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041725/how-to-get-value-from-datagridview-combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `CellValueChanged` event.

```
private void GridCellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //just to be safe
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    var value = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

    if (value != null && value.ToString() == "Yes")  // is completed
    {
       dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Excelent example Amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Datagridview value changed event. And in that event get the selected row and cell value. Based on that value you should set the selected row backcolor.